# How do I use a 'picture' object as a symbol in a graph key?

Tags: r, lattice, grimport

I'm creating a graph using xyplot() from lattice, and using the grImport package to plot a picture as a plotting symbols with grid.symbols().

This is a brief version of the code for my graph, where 'mypic' is the picture object (created with grImport) I'm using as a plotting symbol.

```
xyplot(y~x, data=dat,
  panel=function(x, y, ...) {
   grid.symbols(mypic, x, y, units = "native",
    size = unit(10, "mm"),
    use.gc = FALSE,
    gp = gpar(col = "white", fill = c("red","blue")))
})
```

I want to create a legend that shows the same plotting symbol I've used in the graph. I thought something like this would work:

```
key = list(...
  points = list(pch = grid.picture(mypic))
)
```

but it doesn't.

So my question is: how do I pass the picture object to the 'key' argument to use it as the symbol in the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to pass your picture from `grImport` to `key` without modifying the code.

I have a solution, although is is quite ad hoc, particularly since the images in the key move then the image is resized. (I think that could be fixed given some effort.) Anyway, using `key` (or `auto.key`) and manually placing the images at the key will get something close to the desired result.

```
library(lattice)
library(grImport)

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), ind = c("A", "B"))

PostScriptTrace("petal.ps") # from https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v030i04
petal <- readPicture("petal.ps.xml") 

xyplot(y ~ x, groups = ind, data = dat,
       auto.key = list(points = FALSE),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         grid.symbols(petal, x, y, units = "native",
                      size = unit(4, "mm"),
                      use.gc = FALSE,
                      gp = gpar(col = "white", fill = c("red","blue")))
       })

grid.symbols(petal, c(0.55, 0.55), c(0.92, 0.95), 
             size = unit(4, "mm"),
             use.gc = FALSE,
             gp = gpar(col = "white", fill = c("red","blue")))
```

[image: Imgur]